# Why is the link getting doubled sometimes when I use yajra-datatable for laravel?

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

Most of the time when I select a user in the users list, the link would go "localhost:8000/user/1" but sometimes is goes "localhost:8000/user/user/1". I can't remove the `user` in the link `data = '<a href="user/' + data + '>' + data + '</a>';` because most of the time it shows the user page correctly.
This is the code under the UserController

```
public function getUsers(Request $request) {
    if ( $request->ajax() ) {
        ...
        return Datatables::of($data)
            ->addColumn('id', function($row) {
                return $row['id'];
            })
            ->addColumn('name', function($row) {
                return $row['name'];
            ->rawColumns(['id', 'name'])
            ->make(true);
    }
}
```

This is the script for users index.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var table = $('.yajra-datatable').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ url('users/list') }}",
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'id',
                    name: 'id',
                    "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        if(type === 'display'){
                            data = '<a href="user/' + data + '>' + data + '</a>';
                        }

                        return data;
                    }
                },
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            ],
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add slash in the front of url

```
data = '<a href="/user/' + data + '>' + data + '</a>';
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark this as answer after a month if the error won't show up again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the thing causing the problem could be the href attribute because if you are on the "/user" page the href value "user/1" will add to that so it will give that result like "/user/user/1".

You should make an absolute value for that. Using this approach that could be accomplished. Try to make a complete URL to the user read page, like this:

```
 $(function () {
        var users_url = "{{config('app.url'}}/user/"; // <-- This should be the absolute URL to user page
        var table = $('.yajra-datatable').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ url('users/list') }}",
            columns: [
                {
                    data: 'id',
                    name: 'id',
                    "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        if(type === 'display'){
                            data = '<a href="' + users_url + data + '">' + data + '</a>';
                        }

                        return data;
                    }
                },
                {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            ],
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll mark this as answer after a month if the error won't show up again.